# Django unable to submit form, getting error 'Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices'

Tags: python, django

I have a Django form in which, `Select_Category` will be filtered based on the value selected in `Select_Type`.
I am using an Ajax query to achieve this. When executing, I can see the filter is working correctly as expected.
But when I click submit, I get an error on the page 'Select a good choice. That choice is not available, and the 'Select_Category' field is getting emptied.

### forms.py

```
class Test_Form(forms.Form):
    Select_Type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[('Incoming', 'IN'), ('Outgoing', 'OUT')], initial='Outgoing')
    Select_Category = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Categories.objects.all())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['Select_Category'].queryset=Categories.objects.none()
```

Since the form is not being submitted, I suspect some issues with my forms.py. Can someone help?